# ngrok - vs2017 - Ran into a problem trying to start the ngrok tunnels

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ngrok

I added ngrok in visual studio 2017 and when I try to start ngrok tunnel I get the attached error:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what's wrong there but I can suggest using our free VS extension, Conveyor (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti) which also does tunnelling.

Comment: @JimW I encountered this same error when using the VS extension. Charubim's answer did the trick - just click Ok on the error but leave the ngrok window open. Then try starting the tunnel again

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem on the Twilio tutorial when setting up a ngrok tunnel to receive text.

Lanuch your WebApplication then select "Tools" then "Start ngrok Tunnel". You will receive the error you pasted above. Click "Ok" and leave the dialog window of the tunnel running. Back in your IDE start the ngrok Tunnel again and you should have a forwarding address to use for webhooks and such.